# Libgdx arcball camera and billboard

Tags: libgdx

I just implemented an arcball cam in libgdx

```
    private void rotate(float pitch, float yaw, float roll) {
        tempQuat.setEulerAngles(pitch, yaw, roll);
        rotationQuat.mulLeft(tempQuat);
    }
```

...

```
    float aspect = camera.viewportWidth / camera.viewportHeight;
    camera.projection.setToProjection(Math.abs(camera.near), Math.abs(camera.far), camera.fieldOfView, aspect);
    camera.view.setToLookAt(camera.position, tempVector.set(camera.position).add(camera.direction), camera.up);

        rotate(MyGestureListener.mXAngle, MyGestureListener.mYAngle, 0);
        camera.view.rotate(rotationQuat);

    camera.combined.set(camera.projection);
    Matrix4.mul(camera.combined.val, camera.view.val);

    camera.invProjectionView.set(camera.combined);
    Matrix4.inv(camera.invProjectionView.val);
    camera.frustum.update(camera.invProjectionView);
```

Everything works fine, but one thing is not good:

I have some decal that always rotated to the camera as a billboard:

```
        p.decalPoint.setPosition(p.pos.x, p.pos.y, p.pos.z);
        p.decalPoint.setRotation(camera.direction, camera.up);
```

Now this is broken. Why? How can I fix this?

I need an arcball camera like here:

https://youtu.be/YxNjjyv8W0I

The above code works well, but billboarding not working with the cam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using two rotation matrix and a camfocusvector as an arcball

Quaternions are not suitable for this

Answer (score 1):

You are bypassing the camera and manually updating the matrices and frustum members, but forgot to update the other members. So you'll have to either update the other members (like `position`, `direction` and `up`) as well, or instead use the functionality the camera provides:

- The call to `camera.projection.setToProjection` is not needed.
- The call to `camera.view.setToLookAt` is not needed.
- The call to `camera.view.rotate` would be `camera.rotate`.
- The call to `camera.combined.set` and `Matrix4.mul` is not needed.
- The call to `camera.invProjectionView.set` and `Matrix4.inv` is not needed.
- The call to `camera.frustum.update` is not needed.
- Add a call to `camera.update();`

See also http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1550 for more info.

Comment: private Quaternion getRotatedQuaternion(float pitch, float yaw, float roll) {
        tempQuat.setEulerAngles(pitch, yaw, roll);
        rotationQuat.mulLeft(tempQuat);

        return rotationQuat;
    }
            camera.lookAt(Axis.ORIGO);
            camera.rotate(getRotatedQuaternion(gestureListener.mXAngle, gestureListener.mYAngle, 0));

        camera.update(); It is not working as expected:(

Comment: Perhaps then first explain what you expect. Although that snippets looks very different. So if you have a different question then better ask a new question.

Comment: It will be an arcball camera. So gimbal probleme solved here with my first code. How can I update direction and up vector from here?

Comment: You can update the `direction` and `up` vectors as you like, e.g.: `camera.up.set(whateveryouwant);` Your original question was what is wrong with the snippet you posted, which has nothing to do with gimbal. You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question or ask a new question.

Comment: New question added

Comment: I ended up using two rotation matrix and a camfocusvector as an arcball